# How to assign date to custom directive in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application in `angularjs`. I am developing form where i have one `textbox` with calender option. I am using 720kb date picket pluggin. I am trying to apply various options given in below document. [Link](https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker). `date-min-limit=""` where i can assign date so that previous dates i can block. I tried as `date-min-limit="08/14/2017"` and i am able to disable dates before 14(today.). I want to assign date from controller as `date-min-limit="d"` and in controller `var d = new Date();` But this does not working for me. May i know what is the correct method to assign date in `html`. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this once for javascript

```
var d = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
```

(or) this if you are using `$scope` to bind properties to controllers in angularjs

```
$scope.d = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
```

Returns the string version of date based on the Locale. If you want to customize look on [Moziila Docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Comment: how you can bind a js variable to angularjs in html, i think this is what you need `$scope.d = new Date().toLocaleDateString();`

Comment: Yeah yeah. I do not why i forgot the basic thing.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation states that the parameter is a string. Therefore the correct syntax should be:

```
date-min-limit="{{d}}"
```

I believe it this will not require invoking {{d.toString()}} but you can check that.